# Need to match the repeated words and replace it with a new one using regex

Tags: regex, replace, repeat

I was trying to match a pattern from the below line in linux,

```
$(menu_no),ini_question3.vox,inv_question3.vox,inv_question3.vox,ini_question3.vox,to_question3.vox
```

From the above line i need to find the repeated word and replace the repetition with some other word,

Ex: Here the repeated word is 
    inv_question3.vox,inv_question3.vox 
i need this to be changed to 
    inv_question3.vox,end.vox

I was trying to do a find and replace in vim editor using the below command, but it didn't work,

```
:s/\(inv_question*.vox\),\(inv_question*.vox\)/\1,end.vox/g
```

Comment: Only `inv_question3.vox,inv_question3.vox` by `inv_question3.vox,end.vox`. Right?

Comment: Yes, only inv_question3.vox,inv_question3.vox by inv_question3.vox,end.vox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to replace, but if you want to match duplicate string `inv_question3.vox`, you can try:

```js
let string = '$(menu_no),ini_question3.vox,inv_question3.vox,inv_question3.vox,ini_question3.vox,to_question3.vox';

let result = string.replace(/(inv_question\d\.vox\,){2,}/, '$1,end.vox,');

console.log(result)
```

- `\d`: only 1 number.
- `{2,}`: 2 or more times

Then, replacing with `$1,end.vox,` with `$1` is `inv_question3.vox`

Comment: i just want to replace the second occurrence with a new string in linux.